Problem with Remix nested routes when hosted on Vercel (“Route X does not match URL Y”)
I have a Remix app with nested routes. These are my route files:
app/routes/_in.$team.write-texts.tsx (navigation used in both files below)

app/routes/_in.$team.write-texts.files.tsx
app/routes/_in.$team.write-texts.$publicationId.tsx

Situation:

On localhost, everything works.
Hosted on Vercel, most of the app works:

The $publicationId page e.g. /teamname/write-texts/1 works fine.
But the files page e.g. /teamname/write-texts/files crashes (403) with this error in the Vercel logs:



[GET] /teamname/write-texts/files?_data=routes%2F_in.%24team.write-texts.files status=403

then
Error: Route "routes/_in.$team.write-texts.files"
does not match URL "/teamname/write-texts/files"

I’ve tried labbing with basename in vite.config.ts but no good results.
Any tips?
Update

I am using import { vercelPreset } from '@vercel/remix/vite'; in my Vite config (otherwise, no route will render)
Renaming the file to app/routes/_in.$team.files.tsx works! I.e. dropping the .write-texts part.


Have you read through these Vercel deployment docs to see what you may need to setup and/or configure on the server to properly host/serve your React app?

Try using { vercelPreset } from '@vercel/remix/vite';
https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/remix#vercel-vite-preset

@EkaanshArora Yes, I'm using that, otherwise no route will render

Update: renaming the file to app/routes/_in.$team.files.tsx works, but I’d like to avoid this workaround if I can.
